# Why does my vue.js page isn't able to load when inputting jQuery plus minus buttons? Other pages are able to run smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vue.js

I am stuck with an issue that I am unable to identify/understand what went wrong in my application. However, when I started to build the project in "vue ui" command, other pages in my web-based application is able to run successfully.

```
<template>
<body>
  <tr>
    <table><tr class="break"></tr></table>
</tr>
<tr>
    <table><tr class="break"></tr></table>
</tr>
<footer class="footer"> <div class="container"> <span class="text-muted"> <b-nav tabs justified>
<b-nav-item active><router-link to="MenuTable1">Back to main menu</router-link></b-nav-item>
<b-nav-item><router-link to="MealStep2Table1">Proceed to next step</router-link></b-nav-item></b-nav></span></div>
</footer>
<tr>
    <table><tr class="break"></tr></table>
</tr>
<tr>
    <table><tr class="break"></tr></table>
</tr>
<tr>
    <table><tr class="break"></tr></table>
</tr>
<tr>
    <table><tr class="break"></tr></table>
</tr>
    <h3 align="text-align:left"> <b-badge pill variant="info">
       Step 1: Choose Your Carbohydrate</b-badge></h3>
    <h4 style="text-lg-left"><b-badge variant="primary">Item 1 </b-badge></h4>
  <tr>
<img align="centre" src="@/assets/drawable/bistro.jpg" alt="Bistro" style="width:100%">
    <tr><div class="quantity">
    <b-input-group>
      <b-input-group-prepend>
        <b-btn variant="danger" @click="decrement()">-</b-btn>
      </b-input-group-prepend>
      <b-form-input type="number" min="0.00" :value="quantity" id="step1_1"></b-form-input>
      <b-input-group-append>
        <b-btn variant="success" @click="increment()">+</b-btn>
      </b-input-group-append>
    </b-input-group>
  </div></tr>
  <tr>
    <table><tr class="break"></tr></table></tr>
  <tr>
    <table><tr class="break"></tr></table></tr>
      <tr>
    <table><tr class="break"></tr></table></tr>
  <tr>
    <table><tr class="break"></tr></table></tr>
    <div class="text-center"><b-button variant = "outline-success">Add to Cart</b-button></div>
<tr>
    <table><tr class="break"></tr></table>
</tr>
<tr>
    <table><tr class="break"></tr></table>
</tr>
<h4 style="text-center"><b-badge variant="secondary">Item 2</b-badge></h4>
<img align="centre" src="@/assets/drawable/bistro.jpg" alt="Bistro" style="width:100%">
 <div class="quantity">
    <b-input-group>
      <b-input-group-prepend>
        <b-btn variant="danger" @click="decrement()">-</b-btn>
      </b-input-group-prepend>

      <b-form-input type="number" min="0.00" :value="quantity" id="step1_2"></b-form-input>

      <b-input-group-append>
        <b-btn variant="success" @click="increment()">+</b-btn>
      </b-input-group-append>
    </b-input-group>
  </div>
  <tr>
    <table><tr class="break"></tr></table></tr>
  <tr>
    <table><tr class="break"></tr></table></tr>
      <tr>
    <table><tr class="break"></tr></table></tr>
  <tr>
    <table><tr class="break"></tr></table></tr>
    <div class="text-center"><b-button variant = "outline-success">Add to Cart</b-button></div>
<tr>
    <table><tr class="break"></tr></table>
</tr>
<button class="counter-btn" id="increase1" type="button" data-index="1" data-inc="1">+</button>
<button class="counter-btn" id="decrease1" type="button" data-index="1" data-inc="-1">-</button>
<div class="output" id="output-1">+30</div>

<hr />

<button class="counter-btn" id="increase2" type="button" data-index="2" data-inc="1">+</button>
<button class="counter-btn" id="decrease2" type="button" data-index="2" data-inc="-1">-</button>
<div class="output" id="output-2">+30</div>
<tr>
    <table><tr class="break"></tr></table>
</tr>
</body>
</template>

<style>
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;}
  tr.break {
  height: 10px;
}
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
</style>

<script>
import $ from 'jquery'
$('.counter-btn').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var $btn = $(this)
  $('#output-' + $btn.data('index')).html(function (i, val) {
    val = val * 1 + $btn.data('inc')
    return (val <= 0 ? '' : '+') + val
  })
})
</script>
```

When I checked the output under the vue ui server, it shows that the page has a warning

```
"export 'default' (imported as 'mod') was not found in '-!../../../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!../../../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!../../../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./MealStep1Table1.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&'
<s> [webpack.Progress] 98% after emitting CopyPlugin
<s> [webpack.Progress] 98% after emitting vue-cli-dashboard-plugin
<s> [webpack.Progress] 100%
```

I have installed jQuery into the project. I have also utilized bootstrap/bootstrap-vue into the project.

With that, I appreciate all the help and advice that I can get.